# Angular: How to configure a Date Picker to disable multiple date ranges?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, date-range

I have a list of objects (Ranges) with attributes `startDate` and `endDate`. I need to disable user input on a date picker for dates that fall within these ranges.

For example, I want to disable dates between `09-01-2019` and `09-02-2019` as well as dates between `09-05-2019` and `09-06-2019`.

I tried [angular-mydatepicker](https://github.com/kekeh/angular-mydatepicker datepicker), which has an option `disableDateRanges` but I don't know how to apply multiple date ranges.

Here is my code:

```
<input matInput angular-mydatepicker name="startPicker" 
  formControlName="startPicker" (click)="dp.toggleCalendar()"
                 [options]="myStartOptions" #dp="angular-mydatepicker"/>
```

How can I resolve this or is there another date picker that can handle this use case?

Answer (score 1):

## Filter on Multiple Date Ranges

The [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) provides the `matDatepickerFilter` property, which may be set to a function to filter out dates.

See <kbd>[**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so57904882?file=app/datepicker-filter-example.ts)</kbd>

#### Component

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker with filter validation */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-filter-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerFilterExample {
  dateRange1 = [new Date("09-01-2019"), new Date("09-02-2019")]
  dateRange2 = [new Date("09-05-2019"), new Date("09-06-2019")]

  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    // Prevent dates in ranges from being selected.
    return !(d >= this.dateRange1[0] && d <= this.dateRange1[1]) 
      && !(d >= this.dateRange2[0] && d <= this.dateRange2[1])
  }
}
```

#### Template

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

## Date Range between Min & Max

For the simpler scenario of specifying a minimum and maximum date range, use the data validation properties:

> `max` - The maximum valid date.
>
> `min` - The minimum valid date.

See <kbd>[**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/angular/volegkdxxka?file=app%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.ts)</kbd>

#### Template

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This will work but if I want to disable only one date range. My question is how to disable MULTIPLE date ranges ?! For example I want to disable dates from 01-01-2019 to 01-02-2019, dates from 01-05-2019 to  01-06-2019 and so on..

Comment: @Fatih See updated example for how to filter multiple date ranges.

Comment: I tried with filter also but it want help me. Like I said in my question, I have list of objects with attributes startDate and endDate. And that list is dynamical. Data in that list depend of what user choose. So I cant know which date ranges I need to disable and how many date ranges. It is variable value of objects in list and list size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73433976/multiple-daterange-filter-for-angular-material-datepicker