# Multiple dateRange filter for Angular Material DatePicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

i have a multiple startDate and endDate from my data and i want to use that for disabled date range in datePicker Material of Angular.

I see this issue :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904882/angular-how-to-configure-a-date-picker-to-disable-multiple-date-ranges/73433548?noredirect=1#comment129681283_73433548),
but in the example is for two table, in my case i have a lot of table, so i begin a code with a loop but i don't know how to use it

this is my code :

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Booking } from 'src/app/core/models/booking.model';
import { BookingService } from 'src/app/core/services/booking.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-booking',
  templateUrl: './booking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking.component.scss'],
})
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
  idAccommodation!: number;
  bookingAccommodation$!: Observable<Booking[]>;
  dateBooking: Array<Array<any>> = [];
  dateDisabled!: any;

  constructor(
    private activedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private bookingService: BookingService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.idAccommodation = +this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.bookingService
      .getBookingByIdAccommodation(this.idAccommodation)
      .pipe(map((res: any) => res['hydra:member']))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          res.forEach((element: any) => {
            this.dateBooking.push([
              new Date(element.startDate),
              new Date(element.endDate),
            ]);
          });

          this.dateBooking.forEach((element) => {
            element.forEach((date) => {
              console.log(date);
            });
          });

          this.dateDisabled = (date: Date | null): any => {
            return (
              !(
                date! >= this.dateBooking[1][0] &&
                date! <= this.dateBooking[1][1]
              ) && date! >= new Date()
            );
          };
        },
      });
  }
}
```

Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with Date javascript object you need be carefull

A mat-datepicker return you a date object of type, e.g.

```
Mon Sep 19 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

When you use, e.g.

```
new Date('2022-08-24')
//you get
Date Wed Aug 24 2022 02:00:00 GMT+0200
```

See how add the "02:00:00" -because I'm in GTM+0200. So the first you need is that your range becomes in the way 00:00:00 using setHours

```
res.forEach((element: any) => {
   const el=[
          new Date(element.startDate),
          new Date(element.endDate),
        ]
        el[0].setHours(setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
        el[1].setHours(setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
        this.dateBooking.push(el);
      });
}
```

Equal you need take carefull with "today". So in ngOnInit you can use

```
  ngOnInit() {

    //see how use setHours also in today
    const today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    this.dateDisabled = (date: Date | null): any => {
      if (date! < today) return false;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.dateBooking.length; i++) {
        if (date! >= this.dateBooking[i][0] && date! <= this.dateBooking[i][1])
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    };

    //or

    this.dateDisabled = (date: Date | null): any => {
      return (
        date! >= today &&
        this.dateBooking.reduce((a, b) => {
          return a && (date! < b[0] || date! > b[1]);
        }, true)
      );
    };
  }
```

NOTE: the second approach loop over all the elements of dateBooking. It's looks like slower that the first one but really the time spend (30 days* dateBooking.length) it's not apreciable

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nosmhs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts)

NOTE2: If you need severals "dateDisabled" functions use an array of functions

```
dateDisabled:((date: Date | null)=>any)[]=[]

//  and use 
dateDisabledObj[index]=(date: Date | null): any => {...}
```

Or and object of functions

```
dateDisabledObj:any={}

// and use 
dateDisabledObj[''+id]=(date: Date | null): any => {...}
```

Comment: thanks again for the solution, just when i create a new object of Date is the hours is 00:00:00, like date picker, not like the GTM, because maybe the dates are send by my API REST who return the format like this 2022-07-20T00:00:00+02:00. So this is why maybe i don't need to set hours for mat picker

Comment: Yes, if you received the date from your API like `2022-07-20T00:00:00+02:00` you only need take care with "today". I explain this because I find APIs that return in format only `yyyy-MM-dd`